# Query on Wordpress database returns invalid categories for a post

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, categories

I'm trying to get the categories assigned to a post in the WordPress database via the following query.

However, `prod_Hats` is definitely NOT assigned to the post (checking via the Wordpress UI), however, it IS returned with this query.
What I also find strange is that the prod_Hats row has a mismatch in the values for `term_taxonomy_id` and `term_id`, since I explicitly JOIN tables based on the equality of those column values.

What is wrong with my query?

```
select wt.name,wt.slug,wtr.term_taxonomy_id,wtt.term_id,wtt.taxonomy from 
wp_term_relationships wtr
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy wtt ON wtt.term_taxonomy_id=wtr.term_taxonomy_id AND wtt.taxonomy='category'
INNER JOIN wp_terms wt ON wt.term_id=wtt.term_taxonomy_id
where wtr.object_id=10
```

RESULT:

```
name        slug        term_taxonomy_id    term_id     taxonomy
Must read   must-read   4                   4           category
Tips        tips        9                   9           category
english     english     20                  20          category
prod_Hats   prod_hats   73                  72          category
```

Also, some new categories I add and assign to this post are not returned at all via this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at a query I have to do something similar (not near a database to confirm), my joins are like this:

```
  FROM wp_posts p
       LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id
       LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
       LEFT JOIN wp_terms t on tt.term_id = t.term_id
```

The difference I see is on your line

```
INNER JOIN wp_terms wt ON wt.term_id=wtt.term_taxonomy_id
```

I use `term_id`, not `term_taxonomy_id`